# Firmata C++ library for host?

Tags: serial, firmata

Firmata seems to be a popular protocol for communicating between the Arduino and host computer. However, there only seems to be C/C++ libraries for the Arduino. Most Firmata libraries for the host appear to be in Python. I've found a few C/C++ Firmata libraries for the host, but they seem incomplete and unmaintained. Is anyone aware of a full-featured C++ Firmata library designed to run on the host computer?

Comment: Do you have an update or answer on this?  I am looking after the same

Comment: @JoseECalderon, No. I was researching this as part of a ROS project, but I ended up going with the rosserial_arduino package, which implements its own similar protocol.

Answer (score 3):

[openFrameworks](https://openframeworks.cc) appears to have this capability. It's written in C++.

From [openFrameworks - Communication](https://openframeworks.cc/documentation/communication/):

> **Arduino and other serial devices communication**
>
> The communication module has classes to communicate with other devices
>   by now through the serial protocol. This mainly allows to communicate
>   with devices like the Arduino. There's 2 classes in this module,
>   [ofSerial](https://openframeworks.cc/documentation/communication/ofSerial.html) which allows to communicate with any device through the
>   serial protocol. It can be used to send custom commands to for example
>   an Arduino sketch that will receive them and do something in response
>   like turn an LED on, move a motor... It also works the other way
>   around, you can send messages from the Arduino (or any other serial
>   device), for example the read from a temperature sensor to
>   openFrameworks.
>
> The second class, [ofArduino](https://openframeworks.cc/documentation/communication/ofArduino), is specific to the arduino, it uses a
>   protocol called **firmata** to send messages to and from the arduino that
>   way you don't need to care about implementing the communication
>   protocol from the Arduino sketch to openFrameworks and viceversa but
>   instead you can just send and read values directly to and from any pin
>   in the Arduino.